# Matching orders to guests by turning the table

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, graph-theory

> $100$ boys and $100$ girls came to the cafe. There they were seated at a round table. Each girl ordered ice cream and each boy ordered cake. The waiter mixed things up and put the orders wrong, but there was still $100$ of ice cream and $100$ of cake. The boys were outraged, but the waiter said he could rotate the round table so he could correct the situation. What is the largest number of orders the waiter is guaranteed (however he originally placed the dishes) that he can place correctly, that is, so that the boy gets the cake and the girl gets the ice cream, by teem rotation?

**As I understand it now:**
There is $X$ $-$ a permutation of conventionally $100$ of zeros and $100$ of units $-$ the original order.
There is $Y$ $-$ also a permutation of conventionally $100$ zeros and $100$ units $-$ what the waiter brought.
The question is how many X's there are that can be obtained from any $Y$ by a cyclic shift.
If so, obviously $0$. But that's wrong...

Thought maybe they could ask what number of different $X$ can be obtained by a cyclic shift of $Y$ (guaranteed $-$ take the minimum on $Y$)? (minimum of $Y$ from {number of $X$ obtained by cyclic shift $Y$}, but that's also some nonsense)

Comment: I forgot to specify, the answer must be a natural number

Comment: You can compose one of the permutations with a specific cycle (repeatedly). You are asked to get as many 0-0, 1-1 pairs as possible. It should be clear that the answer is a natural number.

Comment: Try with smaller values first. What is the maximum number of matches that we can guarantee? For example, we can always ensure that 1 person gets what they ordered. Can we do better?